Unable to create connect to data source to Power BI gateway
Got this error when i connected to a gateway created. My data source is a all spreadsheet located in shared drive and gateway installed in some other server and it was successful. but am getting this error when I try to establish a  new connection via my gateway.
Unable to create connection for the following reason: Unable to connect to the data source. Either the data source is inaccessible, a connection timeout occurred, or the data source credentials are invalid. Please verify the data source configuration and contact a data source administrator to troubleshoot this issue.
Details: Metrics (gateway name): Could not find a part of the path
Please have this information handy if you choose to create a support ticket. Session Id: e6fc8cda-b5c2-44e6-89d4-189773c7dbe7 RequestId: 0c1da4d7-095d-4ec2-b5c4-316bb740d91e Cluster URI: https://api.powerbigov.us Status code: 400 Time: Thu Sep 26 2024 07:36:42 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
I tried mapping the Shared drive via gateway server and i am able to access the files  and folders via server once I log in. But when I try to open the file it doesn't allow me to since its all spreadsheet. Rest all doc files are accessible.
Tried using the \xxxxx.xxxxx.xxx\Sdrive since all my files resides here, but am not able to get this issue fixed.
